# how to create a db instnce for aurora mysql using mule 4 rds connector

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, mule4

What are the steps to create a db instance for aurora mysql using mule 4 rds connector(**CreateDbInstance**).
Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify how this question is different and not a duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264883/is-there-any-way-to-create-aurora-mysql-db-instance-through-mule-4. Thanks.

Comment: Here I'm specified it as steps only using rds connector. And there I have just asked for any other ways

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed example with steps in the documentation page of the connector which is described exactly as that: "This demo Mule application creates a DB instance".

https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/amazon/amazon-rds-connector#demo-mule-application-using-the-connector

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is no example values to be set like engine:aurora. Example parameter values will be appreciated. I have tried for mysql engine which is successfully executed but I can't find any examples for aurora. That's why I specified this question as create db instance for aurora.